# Why custom radio does not uncheck after clicking another radio button?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have two custom radio button , I have added a custom tick when clicked to be checked [tick], but when I clcik the second button the first radio button still checked .

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/03vwco7r/

here is html :

```
<p class="payment_module">
    <input id="session1" name="radio-group" type="radio" />
    <label for="session1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/86/49/?random" alt="Zapłać przelewem" width="86" height="49">
        Zapłać przelewem&nbsp;<span>(czas przetwarzania zamówienia będzie dłuższy)</span>
  </label>
</p>


    <p class="payment_module">
        <input id="session1" name="radio-group" type="radio" />
            <label for="session1">
                <img src="{$image|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" alt="{l s='Pay with PayU' mod='payu'}" />
            <a class="payu" href="{$actionUrl|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Pay with PayU' mod='payu'}">
                {l s='Pay with PayU' mod='payu'}
            </a>
        </label>
    </p>
```

Here is css

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin:0;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "✔";
  font-family: 'lucida grande';
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I want whena user click the second button the first button sholud be automatically unchecked,

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have more than one id with the same value on a page. Simply running your markup through the validator would have shown you that. You do validate your markup, right?

Comment: You can not give both radios the same `id` and `for` Change one to `session2` and it should work fine.

Comment: Utr right , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they have same "id" and "for" ,You should change "id" and "for" in second radio style:

```
<p class="payment_module">
    <input id="session1" name="radio-group" type="radio" />
    <label for="session1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/86/49/?random" alt="Zapłać przelewem" width="86" height="49">
        Zapłać przelewem&nbsp;<span>(czas przetwarzania zamówienia będzie dłuższy)</span>
  </label>
</p>


    <p class="payment_module">
        <input id="session2" name="radio-group" type="radio" />
            <label for="session2">
                <img src="{$image|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" alt="{l s='Pay with PayU' mod='payu'}" />
            <a class="payu" href="{$actionUrl|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Pay with PayU' mod='payu'}">
                {l s='Pay with PayU' mod='payu'}
            </a>
        </label>
    </p>
```

session1 ===> session2